# Deleting *char[]

Tags: c++

If I try to delete a char I get an access violation error.

Heres my code:

```
int main()
{
    char *myString = new char[32];
    myString = "Hello";
    cout << myString;
    cin.get();

    delete [] myString;
    return 0;
}
```

Ive also tried

```
delete myString
```

but im still get access violation errors

Comment: This is a good reason why you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of pointers when doing string handling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the line

```
 myString = "Hello";
```

the pointer `myString` no longer points to the array you've allocated, but to a string literal. The line

```
delete [] myString;
```

then attempts to delete the literal (which results in a crash).

You can copy a string with `strcpy`, or better yet, use `std::string`.

```
std::string myString = "Hello";
cout << myString;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do i initialize a C style string on the heap? do i need to use strcpy?

Comment: @user1352609 use `strdup()`, see my answer.

Comment: If you *really* can't use `std::string` (why?), then yes, you have to use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *myString = new char[32];
myString = "Hello";
```

This re-assigns the `myString` variable to something else (specifically, to the constant "Hello" string). Don't do that. If you really need a char pointer, use

```
strcpy(myString, "Hello");
```

or even better

```
char *myString = strdup("Hello");
```

and then free the allocated memory using

```
free(myString);
```

instead of

```
delete [] myString;
```

which would be an error.

but **do not do that.** Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Why is strdup better?  It's not even part of the standard.  And if you're going to recommend it, you should mention that you must call `free()` on the pointer, and not `delete []`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Because it doesn't have the potential of writing out of bounds. `strcpy()` does. And `strncpy()` also does it the programmer fails to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to delete memeory where "Hello" is allocated.
You need to use strcpy to copy content instead of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You get the access violation because of the following line, your pointer no longer looks at the dynamic memory you allocated and is pointing to a literal "hello" instead which you can't delete....

```
myString = "Hello";
```

That Line also isn't going to do what you want, you need to use (Note that you don't need to new/delete in this change)

```
char myString[32];
strcpy(myString,"Hello")
```

or better `strncpy`... look it up on Google or in a book.

Or even better if you are trying to use c++

```
std::string myString;
myString = "Hello";
```